# Определение местоположения устройства владельца

Tags: php, javascript, геолокация

Первый раз сталкиваюсь с задачей определения локации устройства не пользователя, вошедшего на сайт, а конкретного устройства (скорее всего iPhone).

Владелец сайта хочет, чтобы пользователи были в курсе, где именно он находится в данный момент в период 1 дня.

Подскажите направление, как реализовать данный функционал средствами JS, PHP.
Быть может, есть такой API у Google (поиск не дал нужных результатов).

Comment: У андроида пишут есть стандартная фича Location History, у Windows Phone и iOS сервисы поиска телефона windowsphone.com и icloud.com.

Comment: @user3774771 Про Location History я нашел. А вот как к нему обратиться, и возможно ли это - вот дилемма.

Comment: @Visman [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а я не вижу к этому вопросу ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, ответа на данный вопрос, нет.
Данная задача решается разработкой небольшого мобильного приложения, отдающего данные свое местоположения.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/249994)

Comment: Ну как это не является. Отсутствие результата тоже результат. Учитывая, что я автор вопроса, решение за ответ принимаю самостоятельно.